# Mongo DB Join array in 2 different collections

Tags: linq, mongodb-query

I am new to Mongo DB and queries. It will be highly appreciated if someone can help me querying the relevant data. I have 2 collections: Order & ReturnRequest. Order has an array of OrderItems and ReturnRequest has reference to orderID and an array of returnItems. I need to get all the returnItems , but the price of item is in OrderItem array of Order Collection
The Order Collection is as below

```
    {
    "_Orderid": "d991e92a-766c-054e-9ad8-1c902acc6efc",
    "OrderItems": {
       "id": "d991e92a46831",
       "ProductID": "abc.",
       "VendorID": "abv",
       "Quantity": "5",
       "UnitPrice": "220",
       "Currency": "USD"
       }
    }
```

The ReturnRequest collection is as below

```
    {
    "_returnid": "1qqwerda-766c-054e-9ad8-1c902acc6efc",
    "vendorID": "abv",
    "orderId": "d991e92a-766c-054e-9ad8-1c902acc6efc"
    "ReturnItems": {
        "returnItemid": "AAARTY92a46831",
        "ProductID": "abc",
        "Quantity": "2",
       }
    }
```

I need to get the result as

```
    {
    "Orderid": "1qqwerda-766c-054e-9ad8-1c902acc6efc",
    "vendorID": "abv",
    "Currency":"USD",
    "ReturnRequestid": "1qqwerda-766c-054e-9ad8-1c902acc6efc",
    "ReturnItemid": "AAARTY92a46831",
    "ProductID": "abc",
    "Quantity": "2",
    "Price" :"220"
    }
```

Conditions are to join VendorID, OrderID, ProductID between the said collections

Answer (score 1):

Use MongoDB [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) for this purpose.

```
ReturnRequest.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Order",
      localField:"orderId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "orderDetails"
  },
  {
    $unwind: { 
      path: "orderDetails",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",       //ReturnRequest will have _id. if not then you can put $_returnid here instead of $_id.
      "Orderid": { $first: "$_returnid" },
      "vendorID": { $first: "$vendorID" },
      "Currency": { $first: "$orderDetails.OrderItems.Currency" },
      "ReturnRequestid": { $first: "$_returnid" },
      "ReturnItemid": { $first: "$ReturnItems.returnItemid" },
      "ProductID": { $first: "$ReturnItems.ProductID" },
      "Quantity": { $first: "$ReturnItems.Quantity" },
      "Price": { $first: "$orderDetails.OrderItems.UnitPrice" }
    }
  }
]);
```

This is considering that **ReturnRequest** has single **Order** document matching. If there are more than one **Order** documents matching for a **ReturnRequest**, then consider grouping based on **orderId** than **_returnid**.

Comment: Sorry Swapnil. Can you please convert this to LINQ for better understanding. That would be highly helpful. -Thanks